# Deobfuscate variable names in javascript

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I need to deobfuscate a piece of javascript code.

Most of the stuff were written in hex, so I had no problem with that, but I am stuck on the variable names, which seem to have invalid hex.

For example here is a specific variable name:

```
var _0xd05bx1 = "...";
```

I can not recognize what type of coding is this. The `0xd05b` is a valid hex coding but produces some gibberish. However I don't understand the `x1` part?

Comment: It might be random gibberish for all you know. If it was obfuscated to prevent snooping, they likely wouldn't have made it possible to fix the names.

Comment: Usually the obfuscation does not retain _any_ information about the original name of the variable. Are you trying to deobfuscate a particular implementation's output?

Comment: @Carcigenicate you are right, it seems like it is not possible to fix the names. I am going to leave it at that